# jQuery live check input changes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am stuck with a new code, and I seek a smart one-way efficient solution. 
I want to accomplish something similar to Twitter, Let's say we have two
inputs of type=Text, and once one changes we either removeAttr("disabled", "disables"); or attr("disabled", "disabled"), I know this is easy to accomplish when checking one field, but lets say I changed on Field, and next I change the other field, and all of the sudden I decide to change one of them back, or vice versa or both back to previous values, so that the submit button changes between disabled/enabled.

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xu9XH/

```
<input type="text" value="Carl" name="first_name" maxlength="15" id="firstname" />
<input type="text" value="Johnson" name="last_name" maxlength="15" id="lastname" />
<br /><br />
<button id="senddata" disabled="" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Not sure if .each() would work?

Comment: You can use the `placeholder` HTML5 attribute to define the default text. It will be shown if the field is empty but isn't a real value.
More info on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder

Comment: No, no, no! Test my jsfiddle, I read the value from the value attribute, as it does not change when typing, what does however change it the actual value with-in the text field input, not it's value attribute, that's why I am reading the value attribute and storing it as the old value to compare with input.val.

Comment: Do you want to be able to submit as soon as the value of both fields is different of Carl Johnson? In other words, do you want to be able to submit when field 1 equals 'Carl' and field 2 equals 'Crosby'? Or you absolutly need field 1 to be different than 'Carl'?

Comment: No, no, no! 

Let's clear this out: 

1. I go to my account settings, and I am presented with my current values, 

First Name: Carl
Last Name: Johnson

If I just make a change to the first field, the button goes enabled, but if the change made to any of the fields equals their previous values the button will switch to disable, because technically the user has not changed something. But if I changed: 

Field 1: Carlzz
Field 2: Johnsonn

The button will be enabled for submit, if I then go back and change Field 1 to Carl, the submit button must remain enabled, because one field = new val != prev.

Comment: So as soon as one or more field changes value, you want the submit button to be enabled right?

Comment: @Baral Yes, but if I change all the fields back to their previous values, the button will go Disable, if I only change one of the fields (any) to their previous value, and the rest remain with new values, the button will remain enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var inputs = $('input[type="text"]'),
    button = $('#senddata');

inputs.each(function() {
    $(this).data('val', this.value);
}).on('keyup', function() {
    var state = true;
    inputs.each(function(i,el) {
        if ( $(el).val() != $(el).data('val')) state = false;
    });
    button.prop('disabled', state);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xu9XH/4/)

Comment: thanks for this, looks promising, is there a way to dynamically keep track of the fields, as currently your using IDs! can .each() be applied for 'keyup' ?

Comment: @JohnSmith - like that, works with any inputs available, just change the top selectors etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! You saved me, this is a very effective solution, right here. Thanks a lot! :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :)

Comment: Learned something new today! I really Like StackOverflow, and all the solutions they provide. Awesome!

Comment: Now that I know exactly how this code works, I can easily write my own code for other stuff that involve this kind of operation. :)

Comment: How can I make one general, for example: input (of any type), checkboxes, radiobuttons, drop-downs etc, is there a clean way, currently trying out something, but if you know, please inform me, thanks a lot!