# Drop-down set checked state and enable/disable submit button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I posted this question yesterday: [jQuery live check input changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573403/jquery-live-check-input-changes/) - and I got my answer.

Now I am curious if I have drop-downs, checkboxes and radio buttons, how can I keep track of their change.

This is the current code for country :

```
<select id="country-list" name="countries">
  <option value="xx" selected="">Worldwide</option>
  <option value="in">India</option>
  <option value="il">Israel</option>
  <option value="ru">Russia</option>
  <option value="us">United States</option>
</select>
```

The rest is in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XeG5u/

Thanks!

EDIT: My goal, 
[image]

Comment: In the picture, as soon as I switch to my default value, the button is disabled. But if I change to something else it gets enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my own issue. Fairly easy, using find() and getting the default value before comparing in the loop! Thanks folks!

This did the trick:

```
var current = $("#country-list option[selected]").val();
```

And next perform If()-statement ... That's how simple it is...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're doing a lot to enable that button..I feel you could handle most of it with a simple `.change()` event.

```
$("#country-list").change(function() {
    if (this.value == "xx") {
        $("#submit-data").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $("#submit-data").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/XeG5u/1/

Each time the drop-down changes, this event fires. You can store the selected value (accessible in this function as `this.value`) and perform the logic you need.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use jQuery's [`.on('change', ...)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event handler:

```
$('body').on('change', 'select#country-list', function() {
    // When the selected option is changed, this function will be entered
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/PsCdd/).

Comment: Let's say: United States was set to default previously, and I go back and I change to Russia, the button must be enabled, but if I without click submit, go back and change to U.S. as I just had a second a go, I want the button to be disabled, since I never really changed my choice, because it remains the same. Twitter's country list selection is a good example.

Comment: For that you can store the selected country as a variable. I've updated my JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/PsCdd/2/. If you select anything other than Worldwide, the button is enabled, otherwise it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify this greatly:

```
var button = $('#submit-data');
$('#country-list').data('selected', $("#country-list option:selected").val()).change(function () {
    button.prop('disabled', ($(this).find('option:selected').val() === $(this).data('selected')));
});
```